# Dual Boot Win7 Ubuntu 12.10 use 2nd HDD for all My Docs

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7, ntfs, home-directory

My current setup is that I have:
1TB HDD split with Windows OS and Ubuntu OS (with system and Swap of course)
2TB HDD for all my docs

What I want to be able to do is whether I am in Windows or Ubuntu be able to use the 2TB HDD to access all my docs. I have tried this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
but as the second drive is formatted to NTFS it changes the owner of my home directory to Root and I cannot chown it to me. Even if I use gksude nautilus and try it in a gui, as soon as I select my user name as group:owner it changes back to Root straight away. This also knock out pulseaudio as it says it is not owned by me.

Then I tried http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/ 
but this is flawed as then your home directory with all my documents (music, video etc) is not accessible through a terminal command ~/Music.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

The best thing would be if I could get thatfirst link to not change my home directory to be owned by root. Then I can just realign the libraries in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've been using for this:

1. Adding an entry in the **/etc/fstab** file like this: **UUID="YourDataDriveUUIDHere"  /media/"YourDataDriveLabelHere"  ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=002,fmask=113  0  0**
2. Creating **symbolic links** under **Home** folder, either as **Documents**, **Pictures**, etc. or as sub-folders under the such default Home folders.

Comment: So by putting the **uid** and **gid** does that over ride the **defaults** which has nouser (user cannot mount a drive)?

Comment: I'm not an expert but as far as I can remember now this gives ownership of the drive contents (folders & files) to the user. And it's not difficult to change these options later to suit your needs better. But I remember this was the best I could find.

Comment: Thnaks Sadi, I'm just running clonezilla so I don't lose anything, then I'll try this this afternoon.